# Maven site without parent directory

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

I have the following maven-setup:

```
parent-project
  |- libraries
  |- utilities
  |- core
      |- component1
      |- component2
```

in the parent i define all dependency- and pluginmanagement and the infos about the dev-team. utilities containing functional artifacts like the website skin and checkstyle-config, libraries are bundle-artifacts for simplifying the dependencies. The site is build on the core-module and its sub modules. The parent-part of the core pom.

```
<parent>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <groupId>my.group</groupId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>core</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

When staging or deploying the site, the page is located in a "core"-subdir (e.g. /target/staging/core/index.html). Is there a way to locate the site of core in the root?

Atm i use a "dirty hack". On the webserver i created a syslink with `ln -s ./ core` so he don't knows its the same dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was, that maven generates that subdirectory only, when the url for deploying is inherited from the parent. All I need to do was move the distributionManagement section for site deploy and the url element from parent to core.